# VBA Macro Code Stopped Executing

Tags: vba, ms-access, installation

The Setup:

I have an Access 2007 front end (Forms, Queries and Reports) with my data hosted through Azure.

I have the master front end on my desktop that i do development on and when major modifications are made, i distribute the front out to several different locations.

Up until two weeks ago, my development copy worked just as it was supposed to.  Something changed and I can't figure out what happened.

The Problem:

I have many forms that have buttons that execute VBA code.  The problem is on my development copy, the code no longer executes.  If i go to an older copy of the front end on a machine i distribute to, when i push the same button, the same code does execute.

Extra Info:

1. Normal macros work
2. in Trust Center, I have looked at my trust center settings and all seem to be equal to the trust center settings on a machine i distribute my front end to
3. If i copy the development database (on my machine) to one of my distributed machines, the VBA code does not work, so i kept the older copy in place on the distributed machine
4. Under Access Options / Current Database, my settings seem to be the same on the development machine as they are on an older distributed machine.
5. I have searched the net and have looked at as many VBA coding topics as i can find to ensure i didn't accidentally click a button to keep my VBA code from executing.
6. I know my VBA code hasn't changed.  It's not that.  I have too many macros that worked that i haven't changed that stopped executing.
7. If i copy an older distributed copy to my machine and execute the same macro as I do on the most current development copy that is also on my machine, the old copy works on my machine.  No, i did not change the underlying code.

My guess is that one select (or combination of selects) has disabled my VBA code in this development version of the database.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you should download a diff tool like [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/), and diff your project files to see what the difference is

Comment: Did you enable the macro?

Comment: Yes, macros were enabled.  I must have done something to disable all of the macros.  I went to a backup copy of the database (where the macros worked) and tried again.  All was good.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, when all else fails, Compact/Restore the database.

Answer (score 0):

As basdwarf suggest Compact/Restore can be good. if that doesn't work you can open a blank database and import the current database into it and see if thing go back to normal.